# How to compare mycurrent date with quarterwise in android

Tags: android, date

Hi in the below code I have a list of date I am fetching from the Api.From the Arraylist I am checking each and every date .if date between the firstquarter and lastquarter .I am displaying the count.How many times that date was there.

Can any one help me where i did the mistake

example:

```
modifiedtime_list->29-05-2020
Firstquarter-> 01-04-2020
lastDayOfQuarter->30-06-2020
```

expected output:`1`

java:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    localModifiedDate = LocalDate.parse(opportunityModel.getModifiedtime());
                    Log.d("localModifiedDate", String.valueOf(localModifiedDate));
                    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
                    firstDayOfQuarter = localDate.with(localDate.getMonth().firstMonthOfQuarter())
                            .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
                    Log.d("firstDayOfQuarter", String.valueOf(firstDayOfQuarter));

                    lastDayOfQuarter = firstDayOfQuarter.plusMonths(2)
                            .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
                    Log.d("lastDayOfQuarter", String.valueOf(lastDayOfQuarter));

                    if (firstDayOfQuarter.isAfter(localModifiedDate) && lastDayOfQuarter.isBefore(localModifiedDate))  {

                            Count_opportunity = Collections.frequency(salesstage_list, "Opportunity");
                             System.out.println("Count_opportunity is:  "+ Count_opportunity);
}
}
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
    if (modifiedtime_list.contains(
            modifiedtime.compareTo(firstDayOfQuarter1) >= 0)
                    && (modifiedtime_list.contains(
                            modifiedtime.compareTo(lastDayOfQuarter1) >= 0))) {
```

I have broken onto several lines for readability.

You are passing a Boolean value to `modifiedtime_list.contains()` both times (both times `false` as far as I can see). If I guess correctly from your code, `modifiedtime_list` is a list of `String` objects, so it doesn’t contain any Boolean values. therefore `contains()` returns false no matter which dates are involved.

I suggest:

1. Don’t use a list for your quarter. Start and end dates are fine.
2. Don’t use strings for dates. `LocalDate` objects are better.
3. Use the `isBefore`, `isAfter` and/or `isEqual` methods of `LocalDate` to determine whether your date falls within the quarter. Alternatively use:

   ```
       YearMonth firstYearMonthOfQuarter = YearMonth.from(time)
               .with(time.getMonth().firstMonthOfQuarter());
   ```

   Then compare this `YearMonth` with one representing the first month of the quarter in question to see if they are equal.

**Edit**

This is closer:

```
    if (firstDayOfQuarter.isAfter(localModifiedDate)
            && lastDayOfQuarter.isBefore(localModifiedDate))  {
```

I am afraid that you may have reversed each subcondition, though. If I read your code correctly, you are asking if 1st march is after 29th May and 30th June is before 29th May. That can never be true — also not when substituting some other day for 29th May. How would it look with each part negated?

```
    if (! firstDayOfQuarter.isAfter(localModifiedDate)
            && ! lastDayOfQuarter.isBefore(localModifiedDate))  {
```

Think of “not after” as “before or on”. And “not before” as “on or after”.

Comment: how to find lastmonthyear ?

Comment: based on your suggestion I was updated my code.can u pls have a look

Comment: Frankly I find it unfair rewriting the question into such a different one after I have put an effort into answering the original question. This once I have added an edit at the bottom trying to address the new question briefly. It would be better to add the new question either as an addition to your original question so that readers can still see the answer as an answer to the original question. Or to ask a completely new question. In your new question you may include a link back to this one for context if it might be relevant.

Comment: if (! firstDayOfQuarter.isAfter(localModifiedDate)
            && ! lastDayOfQuarter.isBefore(localModifiedDate))  { also giving me same output

Comment: Are you ever using `Count_opportunity` for anything? You are printing `Count_30`, but those two variables seem unrelated?

Comment: output:Count_opportunity:  9(wrong output but in server with only may month data available count of opportunity 1)

Comment: Let continue this discussion in chat